# What kind of creature bit the enemy's leg in China in Skyfall?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall

What kind of animal was it that looks like a giant lizard in the China scene? What is the actual name of that creature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was a [Komodo dragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon), though these are not indigenous to Macau, one of the Special Administrative Regions of China, where that casino scene was staged.